# Dynamically assign ansible_fqdn during play

Tags: ansible

I am using GCP as one of my inventory sources, challenge being we don't have fqdn or suffix exposed.

Ansible_host is set to vm instance IP from GCP.

I created a label for domain membership, the value being the domain name.

The second part of the domain label is alwasys '.somedomain'.

I am attemping to use the above values to build a string to set ansible_fqdn dynamically so I can set ansible_host to its fqdn during a play.

Playbook:

```
---
- name: Patching - pre checks
  hosts: "{{ target_hosts | default('all') }}"
  gather_facts: false

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Include environment variables for GCP Windows Domain Members
      include_vars:
        dir: group_vars/gcp
      when:
         - labels.domainmembership is defined
         - '"windows" in labels.operatingsystem'

    - name: Set facts for identified GCP Domain Members
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        domainlabel_secondpart: '{{ ".somedomain" }}'
        ansible_fqdn: "{{ hostvars[labels.domainmembership] + domainlabel_secondpart }}"
        ansible_host: "{{ ansible_hostname_full }}"
        cacheable: yes
      when:
         - labels.domainmembership is defined
         - '"windows" in labels.operatingsystem'
```

Instead of getting the value of hostvars[labels.domainmembership] (whih is domain1) to build the string I get the following error:

```
TASK [Set facts for identified GCP Domain Members] *****************************
fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['domain1']\" is undefined. \"hostvars['domain1']\" is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/runner/project/pre-checks-test.yml': line 36, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Set facts for identified GCP Domain Members\n      ^ here\n"}
```

A host from GCP inventory source as it appears in ansible:

```
{
  "ansible_host": "10.0.0.2",
  "canIpForward": false,
  "cpuPlatform": "Intel Cascade Lake",
  "creationTimestamp": "2023-04-26T23:55:38.932-07:00",
  "deletionProtection": false,
  "name": "server1",
  "project": "someproject",
  "startRestricted": false,
  "status": "RUNNING",
  "labels": {
    "domainmembership": "domain1",
    "operatingsystem": "windows"
  }
}
```

How do I dynamically set the ansible_fqdn using the domain value as above?

Comment: Why don't you [compose](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_inventory.html#parameter-compose) *ansible_fqdn*?

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. Is there a way to do that conditionally like my attempt in the playbook?

Reason is that only a subset of hosts will have that label and need to have fqdn set. Any help with examples you could provide would be appreciated.

Comment: Since composed variable are Jinja templated, you would be able to use `omit` conditionally to not set the variable for the hosts not having the said label

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working with the following code in the inventory source using Compose (thanks for everyone's input/help):

```
---
plugin: google.cloud.gcp_compute
projects:
  - project1
  - project2
  - project3
filters:
  #- status = RUNNING
  #- scheduling.automaticRestart = true AND status = RUNNING
keyed_groups:
  # Create groups from GCE labels
  - prefix: gcp
    key: labels
  - prefix: gcp_project
    key: project
hostnames:
  # List host by name instead of the default public ip
  - name
compose: 
  ansible_host: name ~ "." ~ labels.domainmembership ~ ".local"
```

Which gives the following value for ansible_host when a vm named "server1" has a domainmembership label with the value "domain1" :

```
"ansible_host": "server1.domain1.local"
```